# classList.toggle('class', true) vs classList.add

Tags: javascript

As the title says. I can't seem to see the difference between the two, and I can't seem to see the point of the second argument for toggle.

Can someone explain to me?

Comment: https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#interface-domtokenlist

Comment: Please note device support issues noted in my comment below.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is no difference; the second argument to `toggle` is to make this kind of thing more convenient:

```
if (hide) {
    el.classList.add('hidden');
} else {
    el.classList.remove('hidden');
}
```

as:

```
el.classList.toggle('hidden', hide);
```

Comment: For those who came here looking for toggle feature. Just do el.classList.toggle('hidden'). It will toggle the class

Comment: Please be aware, IE11 and older Android devices do NOT support that second argument.  If you need broad legacy support, you must write out the conditional with both classList.add and classList.remove methods or polyfill.

Answer (score 1):

There's a small difference, `classList.toggle()` with the **force** argument set to true does the same as `classList.add()`, but it returns a different value.

`classList.toggle()` with the force argument set returns `true` when a class is successfully added, and `false` when it’s successfully removed, while `classList.add()` and `classList.remove()` returns undefined.

```
// returns undefined
classList.add('myClass'); 
classList.remove('myClass'); 

// returns true if class was added, false if it wasn't for some reason
var was_added = classList.toggle('myClass', true) === true;

// returns false if class was removed, true if it wasn't removed for some reason
var was_removed = classList.toggle('myClass', false) === false;
```

so it makes it easier to check that the adding/removing was successful

Comment: It just returns what’s passed to it in that case, though, which is not particularly useful.

Comment: @minitech - true, but that's the only real difference in how they work, and it does check if the class was actually added or not.

Comment: No, it always returns `force`.

Comment: According to the spec it doesn't, it clearly states "Returns true if token is **now present**", meaning it returns true if the class is present in the classList, it does not neccessarely return `force`.

Comment: When will those be different?

Comment: If it for some reason fails to add or remove the class.

Comment: And what possible reason could that be? Sorry to poke, but I’d just like to make sure people don’t get the wrong impression about the reliability of standard functions. In Gecko, for example, it [doesn’t seem to be able happen at all](https://github.com/mozilla/gecko-dev/blob/d2c452e65327743584b7dbd8d697265258ac7bf6/dom/base/nsDOMTokenList.cpp#L297), and the common shims literally use `return force;`.

Comment: It probably never will happen, but that's still what it returns, wether or not the modification of the tokenlist was successful, and that's the difference in how `add` and `toggle` work, what they return.

Answer (score 1):

https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#interface-domtokenlist :

> If *force* is not given, "toggles" *token*, removing it if it’s present and adding it if it’s not. If *force* is true, adds *token* (same as add()). If *force* is false, removes *token* (same as remove()). Returns true if *token* is now present, and false otherwise.

I think the spec is clear enough.

Answer (score 1):

the second parameter could be an expression that returns TRUE or FALSE.
for instance

```
var isEven  = function(x) { return !( x & 1 ); };

// if element already has even class it does nothing, else it will add even class
element.classList.toggle('even', isEven(2))

// if element has even class, it will remove it, otherwise does nothing
element.classList.toggle('even', isEven(1))
```

I think you can do the same with if statements, but this is more elegant